# Response selector -- using variables

Tags: xpath, scrapy, selector

My scrapy script returns results when xpaths are hard coded but does not work with variables. What am I missing

The following works:

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[(@id = "abc")]').extract()
```

The following DOES NOT works:

```
response.xpath("{}".format(xpath_variable)).extract()
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the value of `xpath_variable`?

Comment: It's a string of the form "//*[@id='itemid']" I verified that the coach is correct and works both in chrome and in my script (when hard coded)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out. There was a mistake with my code since I was replacing text within the xpath. Variables do in fact work. Thanks for looking into this Tomas!